# After popping from the stack twice, top() always returns 32. What's wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, stack

This my code out of context. This is after the stack is already filled. The variable first always gets the correct value from the top of the stack on the first pass after the object is popped from the stack, but the variable second ALWAYS returns 32. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
        stack<char> stack;
        stack.pop();
        int first=atoi(&stack.top());//convert character to int
        stack.pop();

        int second=atoi(&stack.top());//convert character to int
```

Comment: There are so many flaws in that code, I don't even know where to start telling about them.

Comment: How can you do `stack<char> stack;`? This is the same as ` int int;` which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You never put anything into the stack.

Comment: Key sentence: "this my code out of context." By the time i'm going through these lines of code, my stack is already filled. I just don't want to post all my code because this is the part of my code that I need assistance with. Second, stack is the name of the stack. It works.

Comment: @PeteBecker: What do you mean? Unless I miss something crucial, you will get an error like `error: 'std::stack<char> stack' redeclared as different kind of symbol`.

Comment: @EricAgredo: "It works" is not a legitimate reason to do something. In any case, you didn't even show the definition of `stack`, so we don't even know what the stack is "filled" *with*.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - try it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Well, obviously that error message was copy'n'pasted from the actual try :) So I'm afraid I still don't get it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - it wasn't obvious, in part because it works for me. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker: If I understand correctly, VC++ swallows `#include <stack>
int main() { using std::stack; stack<char> stack; }` even with `/Za`, but GCC doesn't.

Comment: @ChristianHackl -- I used clang and g++. Both accepted it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Which version and which compiler settings? I don't have g++ or clang on this machine here, but all online compilers I've tried failed to compile this piece of code, with various versions and options of the compilers.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - this is just name hiding.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Far be it from me to argue with a project editor of the C++ standard itself... but if this is allowed, then why can't I get g++ or clang to compile `#include <stack> int main() { using std::stack; stack<char> stack; }`, and how did you manage to do so? Are we actually talking about the same piece of code?

Comment: @ChristianHackl - it's that `using std::stack;`: it injects `stack` into `main`, and that's why there's a conflict. I had `using namespace std;` in global scope, so no problem there. And, of course, naming it correctly, i.e., `std::stack`, is the **right** answer. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker: OK, thanks. For a moment, I almost thought g++ and clang got such a fundamental thing wrong while VC++ got it right. (Of course `std::stack` is the right answer; that was never disputed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert a single character in the range `'0'` to `'9'` to an integer value, just subtract `'0'`. `atoi` expects a nul-terminated string, so won't work here.